# How to handle event on html render by computed function in vue js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using vue 2. I have a text get from api.

```
"Hello everyone! My name is [input]. I'm [input] year old".
```

Now, I have to replace the [input] with an html input and handle the onKeyUp for this input.

What I have to do?

I used computed render html, but it not work with v-on:xxx.

```
content.replaceAll('[answer]', '<input type="text" class="input_answer" v-on:click="handleInput()"/>')
```

Thanks!

Comment: you mean when some inputs in the `input` tag then that value should replace the `[input]` in this string "Hello everyone! My name is [input]. I'm [input] year old" on keyUp event?

Comment: 1: I'm have a string "Hello everyone! My name is [input]. I'm [input] year old" get from api.
2: I have to replace the [input] with an html input. 
3. When user text into input. I can get value from user text. 
Ex: User text: Hello everyone! My name is Jerry. I'm 5 year old.
I'm get name => jerry and old = 5.

Comment: okay what do you mean by this? `content.replaceAll('[answer]', '<input type="text" class="input_answer" v-on:click="handleInput()"/>')` why have you used this?

Comment: 1. I have a string get from api
``Dan got 90 points for the Maths test, 70 points for the Science test, 80 points for the English test. The average point of the four tests Dan got was [answer] points.
Jenny's family consumes 50 kg of rice in January, 55 kg in February and 45 kg on March. On average, Jenny's family consumes [answer] kg of rice a month.``
2. Now, i have render in frontend.
[link]https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AduuyKhGQ4oSga8PGMSZDbCPFH3uvGfr/view?usp=sharing.<br>
-When user click Question 1 so forcus input 1.<br/>
-When user click submit, will post all answers with api.

Comment: Will check it and try to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending an hour and so on this requirement, I came up with the solution.

Here you go (I added all the descriptive comments/steps in the below code snippet itself) **:**

```js
// Template coming from API
var textFromAPI = "<p>Hello everyone! My name is [input]. I'm [input] year old</p>";

// getting the array of input tags. So that we can loop and create the proper input element.
const matched = textFromAPI.match(/(input)/g);

// Iterating over an array of matched substrings and creating a HTML element along with the required attributes and events.
matched.forEach((el, index) => {
    textFromAPI = textFromAPI.replace('[input]', `<input type="text" id="${index + 1}" v-model="inputValue[${index}]" v-on:keyup="getValue"/>`);
})

// Here, we are compiling the whole string so that it will behave in a Vue way.
var res = Vue.compile(textFromAPI)

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    compiled: null,
    inputValue: []
  },
  render: res.render,
  staticRenderFns: res.staticRenderFns,
  mounted() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.compiled = res;
    })
  },
  methods: {
    getValue() {
      // Here you will get the updated values of the inputs.
      console.log(this.inputValue);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @ Rohit Jíndal, but!
When I use vue2 and it doesn't work. And there is an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'string')
```

I build this to a component and use anywhere in my project.

```
<render-html :text="question.quest_content" @handleAnswer="handleAnswer"></render-html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I used and it's work.

```
this.$options.staticRenderFns = string.staticRenderFns;
return string.render.bind(this)(h)
```

Thanks so much!